# Information extraction with Spacy with context awareness

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, information-retrieval, information-extraction

I'm trying to extract project relevant information via web **scraping** using Python+ Spacy and then building a table of projects with few attributes , example phrases that are of interest for me are:

- The last is the **300-MW Hardin Solar III Energy Center** in **Roundhead, Marion**, and **McDonald** townships in **Hardin County**.
- In **July**, OPSB approved the **577-MW Fox Squirrel Solar Farm** in **Madison County**.
- **San Diego agency** seeking developers for **pumped storage energy project**.
- The **$52.5m** royalty revenue-based royalty investment includes the **151MW Old Settler wind farm**

Here I have highlighted different types of information that I'm interested in , I need to end up with a table with following columns :
{project name} , {Location} ,{company}, {Capacity} , {start date} , {end Date} , {$investment} , {fuelType}

I'm using Spacy , but looking at the dependency tree I couldn't find any common rule , so if I use matchers I will end up with 10's of them , and they will not capture every possible information in text, is there a systematic approach that can help me achieve even a part of this task (EX: Extract capacity and assign it to the proper project name)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to handle this with spaCy. You'll want a different strategy depending on what label you're using.

- Location, dates, dollars: You should be able to use the default NER pipeline to get these.
- Capacity, fuel type: You can write a simple Matcher (not DependencyMatcher) for these.
- Company: You can use the default NER or train a custom one for this.
- Project Name: I don't understand this from your examples. "pumped storage energy project" could be found using a Matcher or DependencyMatcher, I guess, but is hard. What are other project name examples?

A bigger problem you have is that it sounds like you want a nice neat table, but there's no guarantee your information is structured like that. What if an article mentions that a company is building two plants in the same sentence? How do you deal with multiple values? That's not a problem a library can solve for you - you have to look at your data and decide whether that doesn't happen, so you can ignore it, or what you'll do when it does happen.

Comment: I have gone through the suggestions you mentioned, the point is I'm able to locate the data like dates , or company names and locations ....etc  but I'm facing a problem with assigning a certain value (like capacity) to its corresponding project , same problem is applicable for dates and money, so in short I extract data but unable to assign values properly to their respective owners.

Comment: also please find here an example of combined two project and one owner company in single sentence: "The 20-MW Camellia and 20-MW Winterberry projects in Gloucester County, which will be acquired from Strata Clean Energy." , note also mention of location as well.